# ADT of promitive data type

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm currently studying Abstract Data Type in data structure in C++. Would anyone explain Abstract Data Type  of primitive data types?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, so it is very unclear what kind of explanation you expect. Primitives are usually considered pretty much the opposite of abstract.

Comment: What do you mean by "primitive type"? C++ [doesn't have the same nomenclature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type) as other languages

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.